# Android : Using Handler but still meet NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, handler

I do some network thing, and I understand I cannot do it on main thread. So, I put it into Handler. Here is my code:

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new OrderTask(this, url), 10 * 1000); // periodically run every 10 seconds.
```

And here is my Runnable class:

```
public class OrderTask implements Runnable  {

    OrderFragment fragment;
    String url;

    public OrderTask(OrderFragment fragment, String url) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (fragment.orders) {
            fragment.orders = Order.loadServerOrders(url);  // network code here
        }
        fragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But when It runs, it wll throw exception : `NetworkOnMainThread` at line `loadSeverOrder`. I cannot explain why. Please help me figure this.

Thanks :)

Comment: A `Handler` will execute code on the thread on which it was created. So, if `handler = new Handler()` is running on your UI thread (and it most likely is), then any `Runnable` will execute on main.

Comment: @323go does it really true ? I always think that Handler will automatically add new thread to run work. And I think that why Handler is made

Comment: Yes, it's true. "When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it" (from the Handler documentation). A Handler exists precisely to have access to a thread. If you want a new thread -- create one! `Thread myThread = new Thread( runnable );`

Comment: I will suggest that go with the AsyncTask. better handling of NetworkOnMainThread error.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` or `Intent Service` for such stuff.

Comment: @User117 can you give me example how to periodically run AsyncTask. I have google but doesn't have real answer yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handler will post `Runnable` to the same thread's message queue it was created from.

You might consider using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for running something periodically in separate thread.

Here is code example for this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

worker.scheduleAtFixedRate(new OrderTask(this, url), 
                           0,  //initial delay
                           10, //run every 10 seconds
                           TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Please note, that if you are changing UI elements within you worker - you need to do that within UI context. For this purpose you can use `Handler`.

Another option is to inherit your `OrderTask` from [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). But this is completely another story

Comment: thanks :) but, now worker will works although my activity / fragment has been closed. I want it will close same time with my activity / fragment. How can I do that ? Thanks :)

Comment: worker has `shutdown()` method. Just add `worker.shutdown()` to your activity's/fragment's `onDestroy()`

Comment: Thanks! For example, before creating the stuff written by Pavel, you must declare your runnable and create it Runnable cada5MinutosIncidencias = new Runnable() { 
   @Override
   public void run() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG_TAREAS, "Actualizando incidencias " + getFechaHoraActual());
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
       
    if(cd.isConnectedToInternet()){
     String idioma = "es";
     IncidenciasParser ip = new IncidenciasParser();
     mIncidencias = ip.parse(idioma);
    }
    
   }
  };

Comment: Which would be a better approach for this - ScheduledExecutorService or TimerTask ?

Comment: @JaydevKalivarapu TimerTask will not offload work to the background thread. It will just schedule it, so you still need to create separate thread, use AsyncTask, or other backgrounding approach of your flavor